# How can I share my Zune with other PCs?

Tags: windows, networking, media, zune

I'm interested in listening to my Zune music collection with another PC. Ideally this would include Zune pass content.  Is there a method, technique, or app that I can use to do this?

My Zune collection is on my desktop, and the other PC is a laptop on the same network via WiFi.

*note: I'm not interested in techniques that involve separate media servers, or file syncing (for example Dropbox).*

Comment: We need to know what operating systems on the desktop and the laptop...

Comment: windows 7 on both systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both machines have Windows 7, you could set up a [HomeGroup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/homegroup).

If they don't, set up [File and Printer Sharing](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsfilesharing/ht/enable_disable.htm) on both PCs, and make your Music folder a "shared folder" and point your Zune to there...

As for the Zune Pass Content, that should in theory work on both PCs assuming you are logged into your Windows LIVE/Zune account, and the DRM will work on the laptop when you are logged in...

If you have a Zune, sync everything on your desktop, Zune Pass content, music, etc, and sync it on the laptop, and voila, you have everything on that machine also...Zune Pass Music should work, when you're logged in...

Hope that helps...